# SQL query for searching on multiple record with AND condition

Tags: sql, hana

Can we have the simplest query for the below scenario, (without using multiple query/nested query/ joins)
[Table and search parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Fwh.png)

basically we tried with Intersection, 
SELECT ORDER, PRODUCT FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE PRODUCT = 'P0054'
INTERSECT
SELECT ORDER, PRODUCT FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE PRODUCT = 'P0095';

but we hope there should be a better approach for this scenario. The search condition may contain as many as values with AND condition.
Ideally we are trying to fetch in a single query.

Any input/help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Girish.

Comment: that is not how stackoverflow works. post your query so we can point out any improvements or suggest a better query.

Comment: Hi vkp, I have added the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no repeated rows (order-product is a unique tuple):

```
select order
from SALES_ORDER
where product in ('P0012','P0054')
group by order
having count(DISTINCT PRODUCT) = 2
```

Comment: Hi @GirishBN, sorry, but what do you mean? I'd love to help you, but this query works (i tested it) based on your attached example, without using multiple query/nested query/ joins as you requested. Can you specify / add another example please ?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry i misunderstood the having clause. It worked with the below query:  SELECT  Sales_Order  FROM #salesOrder
WHERE  PRODUCT IN ('P0012','P0054')
GROUP BY Sales_Order
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT) = 2; where 2 is dynamic based on the number of terms in IN clause.

Answer (score 2):

Hope the below query may solve your problem. I didn't tested the query. Please try.

```
SELECT ORDER, PRODUCT 
 FROM SALES_ORDER 
WHERE (PRODUCT = 'P0054' OR  PRODUCT = 'P0095')
 GROUP BY ORDER, PRODUCT
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```